# What does the 'validation' attribute mean in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am reading the W3C documentation for XSLT 3.0 [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-xslt-30-20131212/#element-stream). I notice that some elements such as <xsl:stream> can have the 'validation' attribute, which can have a value of 'strict', 'lax', 'perserve', or 'strip'. What does each value mean? Could someone demonstrate how to use each value?

Answer (score 0):

Which part of

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#stream-validation

don't you understand?

The validation attribute is also present on many elements in XSLT 2.0, and if you're not comfortable with the rather formal language of the spec, you might find the explanation in an XSLT 2.0 textbook more helpful: for example pages 165-179 of my XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference 4th Edition.

Comment: Hey, you wrote that draft, didn't you? I feel honoured by your presence. Thank you for all your explanations to my questions. I can understand the draft most of the times. However, sometimes I do find the language somewhat too formal. For this case, I think it will be helpful if there are some examples illustrating the differences.